# Div onkeydown handling

Tags: javascript, onkeypress

In my code i'm creating divs inside over divs with this code

main page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Set() {
        document.getElementById("maindiv").designMode = "On";
    }
</script>
<script src="Scripts/RichTextBox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body onload="Set()">
<div id="maindiv" contenteditable="true" onclick="javascript:mainDivclick()" style="width: 500px; height: 170px; border-style: solid; text-align: left; font-size: 17px; font-family: Arial; overflow: scroll;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

RichTextBox.js

```
var childclick = false;

function mainDivclick() {

    if (!childclick) {
        insertDiv(document.getElementById("maindiv")); //create sub div in main div
    }
    childclick = false;
}

function insertDiv(divobj) {

    var num = maindiv.getElementsByTagName('div').length; //count number of divs in maindiv
    var divname = "subdiv" + num; //name for a new div
    var newFrame = document.createElement("div");
    newFrame.setAttribute("name", divname);
    newFrame.onclick = function () {  childclick = true; }; //check clicked
    newFrame.addEventListener("keyup", function () { alert('debugger'); }, false);
    newFrame.style.float = "left";
    newFrame.style.width = 'auto';
    newFrame.style.display = 'inline-block';
    newFrame.style.margin = 0;
    newFrame.style.padding = 0;
    newFrame.style.height = 20 + 'px';
    newFrame.style.border = "10px solid #6e6f6e";
    divobj.appendChild(newFrame);
    newFrame.contentEditable = 'true';
    newFrame.designMode = "On";
    newFrame.focus();
    setSelection(newFrame, 0); //move cursor to new div
}
```

for some reason none of the break points doesn't fire on key press (i only need 1 onkeypress event i'm just showing what i tried)

Comment: This line: `newFrame.on("keypress", function () { debugger; });` breaks your code. `on` is not a native method of `iframe` element. Just attach the event listener like you've attached `keyup`.

Comment: i tried ".onkeydown" , ".on" and ".addeventlistener" - they don't work for some reason. I do not know what else to try.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't notice an error in `addEventListener()` too. It should be `newFrame.addEventListener("keyup", function () {debugger;}, false);` A simplified example at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FGQ7G/).

Comment: divobj.addEventListener("keyup", function () { alert('debugger'); }, false); works! but newFrame.addEventListener("keyup", function () { alert('debugger'); }, false); doesn't

Comment: I tested this with IE9 and FF only (having no other browsers at hands right now), both working nice when attaching to `newFrame`. Can you save a fiddle of the code you really use? Btw, `setSelection()` doesn't work in IE9.

Comment: if i change contenteditable to "false" than it works! But do you know a way that it will work with contenteditable="true"?

Comment: If you set `designMode` (and it works), there's no need to use `contentEditable` at all. Anyway, afaik `contentEditable` works only when setting the attribute, setting the property has no influence.